# PDO general error 2050 on localhost but not on live

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2050
```

### Works on localhost but not on a live server

I've simplified it a bit but the main thing is that I use `$stmt` two times, the last `$stmt` overwriting the first (because the first is no longer needed).

When doing this, it works without a problem on localhost, but not on a live server.

```php
$stmt = option('db')->query("
  SELECT *
  FROM municipalities
  WHERE slug = 'hello'
");
$municipalities = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$stmt = option('db')->query("
  SELECT *
  FROM counties
");
$counties = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

### What works both on localhost and on a live server

Now the both `$stmt` variables are prefixed and therefor never collides. This approach works on both localhost and on a live server.

```php
$stmt_municipalities = option('db')->query("
  SELECT *
  FROM municipalities
  WHERE slug = 'hello'
");
$municipalities = $stmt_municipalities->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$stmt_counties = option('db')->query("
  SELECT *
  FROM counties
");
$counties = $stmt_counties->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

### Question

The question is not how I can get it to work, because I've already solved that part.

**The question is, why is this happening?** Why is it different depending on environment? The files are exactly the same. I use the same live database for both cases. The only difference is that the files are stored on localhost or on a server.

Comment: Do you have the same php version on both local and live?

Comment: @Daniel 7.2.1 on localhost and 7.1.33 on the live server. A minor version change.

Comment: If you `unset($stmt)` between the two calls, does that solve it?